# Apache: How can I sort a directory listing numerically?

Tags: apache, sorting

I've got a website with a large directory tree. At some levels there are numerically-named directories, such as 123,45, 67,8 and 67,21. I'd like to sort these such that 123,45 comes after 67,*. Ideally, 67,8 would come before 67,21 as well:

```
67,8
67,21
123,45
```

(Note: ',' could as easily be '.', '-', etc.)

Is there a simple way to accomplish this *within* Apache (either directly or by creating a small plugin for it), or am I going to have to turn the site into some kind of CGI-based thing to make it sort numerically?

Comment: Maybe rename directory name is a better way. rename 67,8 to 067,008, 123,45 to 123,045....

Comment: Zero-padding and other renaming tricks aren't an option. FWIW Windows does this normally, and I suspect other file managers do similarly (the data source is actually from Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need add V=1 parameter, then directory will be displayed in version sorting mode.

example:

http://www.yoursite.com/?V=1

There are more detail information about parameters of apache autoindex module in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#page-header.

Comment: That works exactly as intended... thank you! Now I just need to add it to the configuration so it works like that every time. (An upvote would be appreciated... I suspect I'm not the only person who had trouble finding this option. It never occurred to me to search on "version number')

Comment: Also, adding "IndexOptions VersionSort" to .htaccess sets this mode by default. Thanks again!